# ElasticSearch: Only allocate data in a specific node?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch cluster with 2 nodes, and for a specific index, I only want the data to be allocated in one of the nodes, not the other?

How do I specify this in my configuration? Or is there a way to route this when I actually send the commands to index data?

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using the [allocation filtering](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-allocation.html#shard-allocation-filtering) mechanism.